# Correct way to save special chars in CEWP content link

Tags: multilingual, cewp

I have a content editor web part.  I have content,  it is stored in a file on the site collection in a Folder of the site collection  (not a doc lib)  to hide it from the users as it contains html which contains links to src etc. You can create these in designer or like me deployed in a WSP. (I dont have SPFx on 2013 so this is the next best thing).

However that file contains this char »

Thats utf-8  #00BB

However the file is saved in UTF-8 or UTF-8 with no BOM.  When loaded by SharePoint  it seems to ignore the file encoding and display

```
 Â»
```

Not cool.

If I save the file as ANSI it converts the  » into Â»  and I can delete the Â
and save it and it will appear correctly.

So it appears SharePoint CEWP load routine cant handle UTF8 files and wants ANSI.  Which, if true, if stupid for a multi-lingual system.  So I can't believe that's the problem

Anyone else have this problem, is there a way to save content link files as UTF-8 files,  any trick to it I'm missing  or do you have the same problem and this is buggy?